# Google Safebrowsing Lookup API

Tags: java, rest, safe-browsing

My application uses API to check if a website is listed as malicious in the Google Safebrowsing database.

I'm extremely confused because **I don't understand** if I must send to Google just the homepage or the complete list of all the pages of the website.

If I send them a request via API to check "example.com", will they show me if also "example.com/sample.html" is listed as malicious?

Everything works, but **I'd want to reduce requests** at minimum!

Answer (score 0):

I currently use Google Safe Browsing API and following are the limitations in the API.

- A single API key can make requests for up to 10,000 clients per 24-hour period.
- You can query up to 500 URLs in a single POST
  request.

I previously used one request per time and ended by exceeding the quota defined by the API. But now per request I set maximum of 500 URLs. It helped me not to exceed the limit of the API and it is super fast too.

Try to append URLs into one POST request not exceeding 500 and send to API.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation in the website https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/lookup_guide
says URL = valid URL string following the RFC 1738

Comment: if you use POST you can send whatever number of urls to check

Comment: I have a website with more than 10 millions of pages. Should I send 1 request or 10,000,000?

Comment: awesome website having 10million pages .You can batch it out

Comment: @learningJava: you are totally wrong. SafeBrowsing's APIs has both a url limit and a chars limit

Comment: You can check up to 500 URLs with a single POST request.